# Representing data within multiple tables

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor

I'm going to create a topic in Documentation that I decided to gather its information into multiple tables but I can't find a way to make tables columns width fix. I don't like these unbalanced shapes.

What is the preferred way to accomplish such a task?

> [image: screenshot of example]

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, and I might be in a minority, but I'd rather see that as a matrix, with the flavors across the top and the rest down the side, a la https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/, but it could be I'm used to referencing that table. A lot :).

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: That's good but how about *Descriptions* row? @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: Specially those switches. @Will

Comment: You could just add it to the cell in the first column, below the text there. E.g., the first cell would show something like: **`\p{InArabic}` - Unicode blocks** <br> Perl usage: `example` <br> .NET uses `\p{IsArabic}` syntax instead. Perl supports both notations. --- Just a suggestion, not a big deal.